# Firestore security rule to allow content sharing between 2 users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need to create a collection where the documents can only be viewed and edited by 2 users who both validated that the other is them partner.

My idea was to have a structure like this :
(Joe & Mary are the users uid)

```
users: 
    Joe:
        partner: Mary
        ...
    Mary:
        partner: Joe
        ...

partners:
    JoeMary:
       Joe: true
       mary: true
       field: value
       field: value
       ...
```

My first idea was to use the rule:

```
match /partners/{partnersId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && partnersId.contains(request.auth.uid);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

However it undelined with red arrows and someone told me that it is not working that way. No idea why...

Then I had this idea:

```
const useruid = request.auth.uid
const partner = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.partner

allow read, update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/partners/$(useruid+partneruid)).data.$(request.auth.uid) == true;
allow read, update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/partners/$(partneruid+useruid)).data.$(request.auth.uid) == true;
```

This is a pretty complicated rule with 3 reads that have some cost. And of course there is red evrywhere...

Is there a better option for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to ago about this.  It's hard to know what exactly will work for you, since your requirements are a bit vague.

One way is to simply put both of the user's UID strings into a single array field in the document.  Then write a rule to make sure the current user's UID is in that array:

```
match /partners/{partnersId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.partners.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

The requirement here is that the document must contain an array field called "partners" with the strings for the collaborating UIDs.  The document ID doesn't matter.  It could just be a random ID.

Comment: It seems to be pretty simple and work well with only one read so I feel it shall be the way to go. Thanks...

Comment: For more requierement, I need Joe & Mary to have some data in common (meeting date, marriage date, favorite posts...) that only them can read.